# Kdevelop debugging with Qt sources

Tags: qt, debugging, kdevelop

Hello i have a problem with my code (some signals are not emits), because of that i've downloaded and installed debug syms and qt src (i'm using Debian and because of that did it using apt-get). How can i point a Qt sources to Kdevelop to use it during debugging?